# How can I take special orders in BlueSnap?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, bluesnap

I have a business that sells subscriptions. Each subscription may be sold for a specific price up front, another price for the recurring payment, and have some grace period (trial days before first payment). It changes from customer to customer based on promotions and sales, so keeping a catalog with fixed prices isn't practical.

Is there any way to do this in BlueSnap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this within BlueSnap:

**Virtual Terminal:**

BlueSnap has a Virtual Terminal (*VT*) in the control panel. You may need to get some permissions granted to use it - but once it's available, it's the easiest to use. The VT allows you to select the subscription you want to sell, change all the terms - initial price, recurring price, trial days - and then generate a BuyNow link you can email to the client. The client can use the BuyNow page to pay - but will not be able to change the terms, as they are encrypted.

If you have sales people who all need to sell, you can also establish a user for each sales rep to enter the VT and create on-the-spot subscriptions with payment terms according to the lead they have.

There's a little more details here: https://home.bluesnap.com/features-tools/flexible-integration-options/virtual-terminal/

**API:**

BlueSnap has two APIs available: The Extended API (catalog based), and the Payment API (without a catalog). The way you describe the issue, it sounds like the Payment API is the better choice for you. You can use it to create ad-hoc subscription plans with any given price and terms. Of course, the Extended API also supports override price and override trial days if you prefer. The documentation is here:

Extended API - Create subscription: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/create-shopper-and-order

PAPI - Create subscription: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/create-subscription